# Excel - how to return multiple values based on values from Drop Down List

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Imagine "Varia Single 25/2,3 90" would be merged using `CONCATENATE` formula and selected on a Drop Down List.
Now I want to return all data in the rows that have 25/2,3 and 90 as values.

I have been considering using `VLOOKUP` and `IF`.But not sure if that is the right approach. 
[image: photo]
Please see attached.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `MATCH` to find the desired row. e.g. something like (if cell `Z1` is your dropdown list):

   ```
   = MATCH($Z$1,CONCATENATE($A:$A," ",$B:$B," ",$C:$C),0)
   ```
2. Use `INDEX` to return the desired value in the `A` column, e.g. something like (if cell `Z2` contains the `MATCH` formula above):

   ```
   = INDEX(A:A,$Z$2)
   ```

Then drag this `INDEX` formula to the right to grab the rest of the entries in the row.

This is also possible to do all in one formula, but less efficient because the `MATCH` value must be calculated several times:

```
= INDEX(A:A,MATCH($Z$1,CONCATENATE($A:$A," ",$B:$B," ",$C:$C),0))
```

Note these are array formulas, so you must press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing this formula.

Comment: The thing is that I also need all the other cells that contain either 25/2,3 OR 90. I understand from your formula it only returns one row of data in different cells

Comment: Contain either 25/2 3 or 90... based on what condition?

Comment: Based on that I select Varia Single 25/2,3 90 from Drop Down List